Are mingw and gcc just different in backend?
We know that compilers usually consist of three parts: front-end, intermediate representation (optimizer), and back-end
My understanding of mingw:

mingw uses the compiler front-end and IR optimization of gcc

The mingw back-end generates obj files that comply with the COFF specification, while the traditional gcc generates .o files that comply with the elf specification on the Linux platform


Is my understanding correct?
I googled a lot of information about mingw, but there is little information about the compiler front-end, optimizer, and back-end.

MinGW - and it's newer fork MinGW-w64 - are more like a replacement for the C/C++ standard library. They provide most of what the standard library (like e.g. newlib for other platforms) natively for Windows.
The name MinGW is sometimes used to refer to the whole toolkit, but basically it's GCC targeting native Windows with the MinGW(-w64) standard library.
Windows binaries (.exe and .dll files) are PE files (or PE+ for 64-bit Windows), which are based on the COFF file format.
Note that besides GCC (e.g. https://winlibs.com/) there is also a MinGW-w64 toolkit based on LLVM (https://github.com/mstorsjo/llvm-mingw/releases).
